# Difference between the java -cp versus java -jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jdbc, jar

I work with a Spring boot app and the deliverable is a JAR file. The file needs to be run with the command `java -cp "parser.jar" com.ef.Parser` and execute some operations that are beyond the scope of this question. In this scenario, I have 2 questions.

When I put the command like
`java -jar target/parser-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar com.ef.Parser`, I can run the app. However, when I put the command `java -cp target/parser-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar com.ef.Parser`, I get error 
  `Error: Could not find or load main class com.ef.Parser`

What is the issue here?

I have the `Parser.java` that has package name of `com.ef`

The code is provided below,

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ef.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.ef"}, exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Parser implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private IpAddressService ipAddressService;

    public Parser() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Parser.class);
        application.run(args);
    }



    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("\nHello, Spring Boot!");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The `pom.xml` file provided,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
    <name>Log-Parser</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>RELEASE</version> -->
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--HSQL database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--auto refresh using the dev tool-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--tomcat server-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--live reload of the Sprign boot project-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--H2 database-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
        <!--Commons CLI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!--for the live update with the JSP file-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The second question is when I run the command `mvn clean package`, I get the `parser-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar` in the `target` folder. How to rename the JAR file to the `parser.jar` with the `pom.xml` configuration?

I have tried to rename it manually, but, this doesn't work out.

Comment: what is the package name for `Parser.java` ? can you post exactly same code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your second question:

If you assume that the final jar file should be named `parser.jar` put this into your pom:

```
<build>
   ...
   <finalName>parser</finalName>
   ...
</build>
```

From the docs:

> The filename (excluding the extension, and with no path information)
>   that the produced artifact will be called. The default value is
>   ${artifactId}-${version}.

The answer to your first question is a bit more complicated. In a very lame words I'll try to explain it like this:  the "uber jar" is a bit special and does not contain your classes where you expect them to be. It has a BOOT-INF directory where your classes are located and spring provides the so called "launchers" within the standard location. I recommend you that you open the jar and take a look at it. You may run the application in a similar way then:

```
java -cp target/parser.jar -Dloader.main=com.ef.parser.Parser org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.7.RELEASE)
```

Details are available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features).

The structure of the jar looks like this:

```
BOOT-INF
  |->classes
    |---com.ef.Parser
  |->lib
META-INF
org.springframework...
```

Comment: Do you actually mean `java -cp target/parser.jar -Dloader.main=com.ef.Parser org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`? However, in both cases I get the message of `Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`

Comment: I've copy pasted the command with which I started the simple project on my computer...

Comment: Glad I helped :-)

Comment: I have no idea why the people here so kind, much appreciated

Comment: as I see you from Bulgaria, may I ask you something?

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure you have the namespace correct in your file? It is not shown in your code. Also, check your manifest file - what is the class ran when you run it with the -jar command

2) You need to add

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

To your **build** section in the pom.xml